# Newton's Method and One definition?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

We are some third year students on CS. We have encountered one definition that was not well formed for us. Could anyone describe it more simpler for us? (i.e: how this derivations is adopted?)

Function $f(x)$ in $x=\alpha$ has one repeated or double roots and $f"(x)$ has defined in neighborhood of $\alpha$. if the sequence {${x_n}$} is calculated for solving $f(x)=0$ with newton's method the following is correct ! ($a$ and $b$ is defined between $\alpha$ and $x_n$)

$\dfrac {x_{n+1}-\alpha}{x_n-\alpha} = \dfrac{f"(a)}{2f"(b)} $

Comment: I do not understand what it means to say that "Function f(x) in x=α has square roots"?

Comment: @MioUnio No, it's me who got it wrong, sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Statement:** if $f(x)$ is twice differentiable on $[0,t]$, $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ then $$\exists a \in (0,t) : tf'(t)-f(t) = {t^2 \over 2}f''(a)$$
**Proof:** let $g(x) = xf'(x)-f(x)$, then $g'(x) = xf''(x)$, $g(0)=0$. For $h(x) = x^2$, by Cauchy's mean value theorem:
$$\exists a \in (0,t) : (g(t)-g(0))h'(a) = (h(t)-h(0))g'(a) \\
g(t) * 2a = t^2af''(a) \\
tf'(t)-f(t) = {t^2 \over 2}f''(a) \, |\blacksquare. $$

Now let's suppose $\alpha = 0$ (this is a simple coordinate shift). By mean value theorem, $\exists b \in (0,x_n) : f'(x_n) = x_nf''(b)$. Also, $x_n \neq 0$, $f'(x_n) \neq 0$ (otherwise Newton's method doesn't work).

So we have $${x_{n+1} \over x_n} = {x_n - {f(x_n) \over f'(x_n)} \over x_n} = {x_nf'(x_n)-f(x_n) \over x_nf'(x_n)}$$
Per two previous statements, 
$$\exists a,b \in (0,x_n) : {x_{n+1} \over x_n} = {{x_n^2 \over 2}f''(a) \over x_n^2f''(b)} = {f''(a) \over 2 f''(b)} \, |\blacksquare.$$

Comment: The statement is correct, yes. Assuming a neighborhood of $\alpha$ where $f''(x)$ is defined includes $x_n$ (it wasn't stated directly in your post, but the statement would be meaningless otherwise).

Answer (score 4):

If $x_0$ is sufficiently near $\alpha$, but $\ne\alpha$, then there is a $b$ between $\alpha$ and $x_0$ such that $$f'(x_0)=f'(x_0)-f'(\alpha)=(x_0-\alpha )f''(b)\ne0\ .\tag{1}$$ Computing $f(\alpha)=0$ by means of a  Taylor expansion of $f$ at $x_0$ we get
$$0=f(x_0)+(\alpha-x_0)f'(x_0)+(\alpha-x_0)^2{f''(a)\over 2}\tag{2}$$
for a suitable $a$ between $x_0$ and $\alpha$. If we now divide $(2)$ by $f'(x_0)\ne0$ then the definition of $x_1$ together with $(1)$ leads to
$$0=(x_0-x_1)+(\alpha-x_0)+(x_0-\alpha)^2{f''(a)\over2 f'(x_0)}=\alpha-x_1+(x_0-\alpha){f''(a)\over2 f''(b)}\ ,$$
which is equivalent to
$${x_1-\alpha\over x_0-\alpha}={f''(a)\over2 f''(b)}\ .$$